# Matlib or Plotly Bar Chart Race Graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, plotly-python, plotly-express

I am wanting to produce a bar chart race, I'm not sure what the best way is. This is how I have my data at the moment, but I would want it to skip the 0's.

```
       2019-01-10   2019-01-11  2019-02-10  2019-02-12   2019-03-10
 1         0            0            0           8             0
 2         2            0            3           0             1
 3         1            1            0           2             0
```

I'm just not sure how to add this to a bar chart race, due to only having no 1st column heading and many date columns.

The dataset from above is from this, using this code:

`enrich.groupby(['Username']).count()`

`enrich1 = pd.crosstab(enrich.Username, enrich.Date_Completed)`

```
  Username    Date_Completed   
     1          2019-02-12
     2          2019-01-10
     2          2019-01-10
     3          2019-01-11
     3          2019-02-12
```

Comment: As far as I know at the moment there is not an easy way to use `plotly` for it. Try to check [flourish](https://flourish.studio/visualisations/bar-chart-race/)

Comment: Do you mind to provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)? Here is not quite clear what `enrich` is.